# Address of std::array instance vs .data()

Tags: c++, arrays

> Disclaimer: I only care about std::array. std::vector is obviously
> different.

The `std::array::data()` function returns a pointer to the underlying data in the array: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data

Furthermore, my understanding is that the `std::array` class will act like a simple struct with no overhead, that is, something like `std::array<int, 3>` would be functionally equivalent to

```
struct Int3 {
   int a,b,c;
};
```

This seems to imply to me that we should always find that for an `std::array` called `arr`

```
&arr == arr.data()
```

Will this always be true? or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Do not that `std::array<int, 3>` is functional equivalent to `struct array{ int data[3]; };`  Your example could have gaps between the members (not the it will, just that it could).

Comment: Did you try testing it using a compiler?

Comment: Of course, and I always found them to be equal. I want to know if there is a case where that is not true.

Comment: @NathanOliver Perhaps you are hinting at something subtle, but I fail to see the relevance of your comment.

Comment: @Jason If something is true in some test with a particular compiler doesn't imply that it is guaranteed by the standard ("always be true").

Comment: Ah whoever found the duplicate post THANKS! I assumed that there must be a similar question, but simply couldn't find it

Comment: `std::array<int,0>` [is a tricky case](https://ideone.com/auLya2).